# Identify fairly simple shapes with EMGU

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I am attempting to identify a "T" shape as well as an "L" shape which can be reversed, as shown below. I am using EMGU in C#.

**Shape: T**

[image]

**Shape: L (Regular)**

[image]

**Shape: L (Reversed)**

[image]

I am attempting to consistently detect these different shapes, and I have tried using the Contour approach as shown in [the EMGU shape detection tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp). The problem is that it does not detect the contour points correctly, or when it occasionally does, it is not reliable.

**Contour Logic Output**

[image]

These shapes will be mostly the same, but can be rotated or have a slightly different perspective. What would be an accurate, efficient way to detect these different shapes consistently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried my algorithm with your given images and the results and code are below. I have used thresholding and findcontours function to detect your figure.

[image: Thresholding Function Applied]

[image: findContours Function applied]

[image: Thresholding Function Applied]

[image: findContours Function applied]

Following is the code to find exact contour. Once we find a contour, we can calculate its length or simply store its size. The same contour will always have the same size or length(approximately) whether in any direction.

```
Mat original_image = new Mat();
Mat gray = new Mat();
Mat threshold_image = new Mat();
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat new_image = new Mat();
Mat con = new Mat();

//TrackBar Scroll
    private void trackBarLow_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            low = trackBarLow.Value;
            threshold_value = trackBarThreshold.Value;
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(original_image, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray, 0);
            CvInvoke.Threshold(gray, threshold_image, low, threshold_value, ThresholdType.Binary);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> threshold_I = threshold_image.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            pictureBox2.Image = threshold_I.ToBitmap();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
     }

     private void buttonExactContours_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {
            new_image = new Mat(new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480), DepthType.Cv16S, 3);
            new_image.SetTo(new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar(150, 0, 150));
            con = threshold_image;

            Image<Bgr, Byte> new_image1_I = new_image.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            pictureBox3.Image = new_image1_I.ToBitmap();

            CvInvoke.FindContours(con, contours, null, RetrType.Ccomp, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple, new Point(0, 0));

            IInputArrayOfArrays arr;

            for (int j = 0; j < contours.Size; j++)
            {
                arr = contours[j];

                //textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + CvInvoke.ArcLength(arr, true).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + contours[j].Size.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                if (contours[j].Size < 500) //Value "500" may vary according to the size you may want to filter
                    continue;
            }
            Image<Bgr, Byte> new_image_I = new_image.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            pictureBox2.Image = new_image_I.ToBitmap();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: While I appreciate the response, I do not understand why you are asking me to contact you via email. That does not benefit anyone else on the site that may have a similar question.

Comment: Because the code is lengthy. Anyways does it solve your problem??

Comment: A length solution is neither an issue nor a reason to avoid posting the code. Please edit your answer and post the code. After attempting to implement it, I will then be able to judge if it correctly solves the question, and will mark it accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code. This code is for "Exact Contours Button" click event..

Comment: `con = threshold_image;` What is `threshold_image`? I see `new_image` set above that line but I don't see any declaration or info on what `threshold_image` is.

Comment: My mistake, I have updated the code. Anyway threshold_image"" is the thresholded image of original image so that contours can be found. "new_image"is just a blank image.